# mysql case statement for joining three table

Tags: mysql

there is three table

```
table a
table b 
table c
```

and my query is :

```
select a.title,a.id,b.title 
  from table a 
  case when a.type=1 then 
       inner join table a.id=tableb.id end 
  case when a.type=2 then inner join table a.id=table c.id
```

But this query doesnt work.Can somebody helpe the right way to fetch or execute this type of query

Comment: What are you trying to do ? CASE WHEN have to be use in the SELECT statement

Comment: The very fact that you're trying to do this suggests that your schema violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  Fix it.

Comment: if field type =1 of table a then make join with table b and if type=2 of table 1 then make join with table c

Comment: You must explain your intentions in human language, because your SQL has many syntactical and semantic issues to be understandable.

Comment: In your result set there are no fields for `table c`. Is it used only for filtering data?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use case in the from clause. To achieve this you could use UNION ALL. For instance:

```
select a.title,a.id,b.title
from table a inner join table b on a.id=b.id
where a.type=1
UNION ALL
select a.title,a.id,c.title
from table a inner join table c on a.id=c.id
where a.type=2
```

Comment: how to use limit inside this

Comment: you could use limit at the end of each query in case you need separate limit per category or wrap this in a query and limit the external query instead

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do something like "if this is 1 then join other table than if it is 2", you must join both and select accordingly:

```
SELECT
  a.title, 
  a.id, 
  IF (tableb.title IS NOT NULL, tableb.title, tablec.title),
  CASE a.type
    WHEN 1 THEN tableb.id
    WHEN 2 THEN tablec.id
  END
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tableb.id
LEFT JOIN tablec ON tablea.id = tablec.id
```